# Delphi XE4 - get your local IP in statusbar

Tags: delphi-xe4

Seen most of the examples posted here but none seem to work on XE4. I am trying to display my IP in the status bar.

```
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := GetIP;
```

Functions I have seen here mostly fail on xe4 as they were written in older delphi versions.I would like to get just the local IP,not the one behind the router. Well, for the sake of learning, it would be usefull to know that one too...:)

I tried this :

```
function getIP: string;
type
  TaPInAddr = array [0..10] of PInAddr;
  PaPInAddr = ^TaPInAddr;
var
   phe: PHostEnt;
   pptr: PaPInAddr;
   Buffer: array [0..63] of char;
   i: Integer;
   GInitData: TWSADATA;
begin
   WSAStartup($101, GInitData);
   Result := '';
   GetHostName(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
   phe :=GetHostByName(buffer);
   if phe = nil then Exit;
   pptr := PaPInAddr(Phe^.h_addr_list);
   i := 0;
   while pptr^[i] <> nil do
   begin
     result:=StrPas(inet_ntoa(pptr^[i]^));
     Inc(i);
   end;
   WSACleanup;
end;
```

but it would not work .... many others too ... Seems i am missing something,but what?

Tried this too :

```
function getIPs: Tstrings;
type
  TaPInAddr = array[0..10] of PInAddr;
  PaPInAddr = ^TaPInAddr;
var
  phe: PHostEnt;
  pptr: PaPInAddr;
  Buffer: array[0..63] of Char;
  I: Integer;
  GInitData: TWSAData;
begin
  WSAStartup($101, GInitData);
  Result := TstringList.Create;
  Result.Clear;
  GetHostName(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
  phe := GetHostByName(buffer);
  if phe = nil then Exit;
  pPtr := PaPInAddr(phe^.h_addr_list);
  I    := 0;
  while pPtr^[I] <> nil do
  begin
    Result.Add(inet_ntoa(pptr^[I]^));
    Inc(I);
  end;
  WSACleanup;
end;
```

wont work stops on :  (GetHostName(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));

This however WORKS !  :

```
Function GetIPAddress: String;
type pu_long = ^u_long;
var varTWSAData : TWSAData;
varPHostEnt : PHostEnt;
varTInAddr : TInAddr;
namebuf : Array[0..255] of ansichar;
begin
try
try
If WSAStartup($101,varTWSAData) <> 0 Then
Result := ''
Else Begin
gethostname(namebuf,sizeof(namebuf));
varPHostEnt := gethostbyname(namebuf);
varTInAddr.S_addr := u_long(pu_long(varPHostEnt^.h_addr_list^)^);
Result := inet_ntoa(varTInAddr);
End;
except
Result := '';
end;
finally
WSACleanup;
end;
end;
```

Comment: What have you actually tried to use to implement `GetIP`? What examples have you seen here that aren't working? (And if your question is about XE4, why have you added the XE2 and XE tags?) You've posted a requirement to display the local IP address in the statusbar, but no effort to actually retrieve that local IP address. It also helps if you add the OS you're working with, as XE4 supports Windows, OSX, and iOS (and the newly released XE5 adds Android to the mix).

Comment: The code you posted appears to be compatible with Delphi from a decade or so ago (`StrPas` hasn't been needed since Delphi 2 was released for Windows 95). Certainly you can find another example here or via Google that is more recent. You don't have to search on the exact phrase `GetIP`, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function GetIPAddress: String;
type pu_long = ^u_long;
var varTWSAData : TWSAData;
varPHostEnt : PHostEnt;
varTInAddr : TInAddr;
namebuf : Array[0..255] of ansichar;
begin
try
try
If WSAStartup($101,varTWSAData) <> 0 Then
Result := ''
Else Begin
gethostname(namebuf,sizeof(namebuf));
varPHostEnt := gethostbyname(namebuf);
varTInAddr.S_addr := u_long(pu_long(varPHostEnt^.h_addr_list^)^);
Result := inet_ntoa(varTInAddr);
End;
except
Result := '';
end;
finally
WSACleanup;
end;
end;
```